# Sort list into children using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I am trying to create a tree from a somewhat large list of 13883 objects using Linq to sort the objects into their parent and child groups, each object is associated with a parentId, I can group the objects together using

```
var sortedList = marketItems.GroupBy(p => p.parentId).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
```

but this only sorts them into groups, I'm not yet fluent with linq and cant figure out how to map the children correctly. the null ParentGroup is the top level of the tree. Anyone with more experience with linq able to offer some ideas on how to group the llist correctly.

[image]

```
 public JsonResult GetJsTree3Data()
    {
        var marketItems = new List<JsTree3Node>();
        var itemList = new List<JsTree3Node>();

        foreach (var group in GenerateGroups(connString))
        {
            var node = JsTree3Node.NewNode(group.id_str);
            node.text = group.name;
            node.state = new State(false, false, false);
            node.parentId = group.marketParentGroup;
            marketItems.Add(node);
        }

        foreach (var group in GenerateItems(connString))
        {
            var node = JsTree3Node.NewNode(group.id_str);
            node.text = group.name;
            node.state = new State(false, false, false);
            node.parentId = group.marketParentGroup;
            marketItems.Add(node);
        }

        // Create our root node and ensure it is opened
        var root = new JsTree3Node()
        {
            id = "0",
            text = "Market Items",
            state = new State(true, false, false)
        };

        var sortedList = marketItems.GroupBy(u => u.parentId).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();


        root.children = sortedList;

        return Json(root, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The final result I am trying achive is a tree of items that users can choose from. there is only one level of the tree as the children arent ordered in the sorted list

[image]

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. What is Parent Group 2? Is there some identifier that says, for example, what item is the parent of item Id 2157 (Structure Modifications, Parent Group 2)? Your data does not show anything that would allow me to derive that.

Comment: So the end goal is to come out with a list of parent/child pairs?

Comment: You want to sort list of children under each parent separately? They should be sort by name?

Comment: Can you provide some parent and child  data? It might be more clear to answer

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Things like compilable class defs, sample data, expected output etc.

Comment: Hi I apologise for not being more clear, I have edited the question to add a little more detail, many thanks.

Comment: The code I posted below should provide you with access to the individual groupings and the individual items in separated nested layers. you can assign the items(children) to individual nodes at the 2nd layer and the groupings as parent groups. What else would you like to do with the data?

Comment: Thanks David this worked a treat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, the parents can contain multiple items: I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
            var sortedList = from p in marketItems
                             group p by p.ParentGroup into Groups
                             select Groups;
            //to access the items in each group individually
            foreach (var grouping in sortedList)
            {
                foreach (var Item in grouping)
                {
                    Item.Description///you can access the individual items from this layer...
                }
            }
```

Your code should do this, but to access the grouping items you need to use a nested foreach loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what your end data format is. This groups your items, and then accesses them in sequence of their parentGroup. You can build whatever data structure you would like from this...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your end goal is, but I'm not sure if what you're trying to do can be strictly done with a single LINQ pass. If it were possible, though, I imagine that it would be quite convoluted. You can do it in two LINQ queries quite simply, though:

```
var refDict = marketItems.ToDictionary(k => k.Id, v => v);
var groupedList = marketItems.Select(s => 
                new 
                { 
                    Parent = s.ParentGroup == null ? null : refDict[s.ParentGroup],
                    Child = s
                }).ToList();
```

Then use it like this:

```
var parent = groupedList[0].Parent;
var child = groupedList[0].Child;
```

In all honesty, though, you could just keep yourself to the first line of code then query the dictionary for an object's parent yourself if you ever need it.